# How to create custom function for Json array in My Sql

Tags: mysql, arrays, json, mysql-workbench

Want to create new custom function for fetching json array data and I am using mysql server 5.6 version so I was trying to create custom json function.
can not update mysql version trying with all function that are suggested by stackoverflow
I want my select query to fetch only the value of the key "text". I tried using Regex and Substring but not succeed.

I just want similar JSON_EXTRACT function

Example Json below.

```
{
        "map": [
            {
                "text": "a"
            },
            {
                "text": "b"
            },
            {
                "text": "c"
            },
            {
                "text": "d"
            },
            {
                "text": "e"
            },
            {
                "text": "f"
            }
        ]
    }
```

output:
[a,b,c,d,e,f]

I tried with

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `json_extract_c`(
details TEXT,
required_field VARCHAR (255)
) RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
    NO SQL
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
  DECLARE search_term, val TEXT;
  DECLARE pos INT signed DEFAULT 1;
  SET details = SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, "{", -1);
  SET details = SUBSTRING_INDEX(details, "}", 1);
  SET search_term = CONCAT('"', SUBSTRING_INDEX(required_field,'$.', - 1), '"');
  searching: LOOP
    SET pos = LOCATE(search_term, details);
    
    WHILE pos > 0 AND RIGHT(LEFT(details, pos-1), 1) = '\\'
    DO
      SET details = SUBSTR(details, pos+LENGTH(search_term));
      SET pos = LOCATE(search_term, details);
    END WHILE;
    -- Return NULL if not found
    IF pos <= 0 THEN
      RETURN NULL;
    END IF;
    SET pos = LENGTH(search_term)+pos;
    SET details = SUBSTR(details, pos);
    SET val = TRIM(details);
    IF LEFT(val, 1) = ':' THEN
      RETURN TRIM(
        TRAILING ',' FROM 
        TRIM(
          SUBSTRING_INDEX(
            TRIM(
              BOTH '"' FROM TRIM(
                SUBSTR(
                  val
                , 2
                )
              )
            )
          , '"', 1
          )
        )
      );
    ELSE
      ITERATE searching;
    END IF;
  END LOOP;
END
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```sql
CREATE FUNCTION json_extract_c ( details TEXT,
                                 required_field VARCHAR (255) ) 
RETURNS text CHARSET utf8mb4
NO SQL
DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
SET @json := details;
SET @field := required_field;
SET @output := '[';
WHILE LOCATE(@field, @json) DO
    SET @json := SUBSTRING(@json FROM LOCATE(@field, @json));
    SET @json := SUBSTRING(@json FROM 1 + LOCATE(':', @json));
    SET @json := TRIM(@json);
    SET @value := LEFT(@json, LEAST(LOCATE(' ', CONCAT(@json, ' ')),
                                    LOCATE(',', CONCAT(@json, ',')),
                                    LOCATE(']', CONCAT(@json, ']')),
                                    LOCATE('}', CONCAT(@json, '}'))) - 1);
    SET @json := SUBSTRING(@json FROM 1 + LENGTH(@value));
    SET @output := CONCAT(@output, @value, ',');
-- or SET @output := CONCAT(@output, TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM @value), ',');
END WHILE;
RETURN CONCAT(TRIM(TRAILING ',' FROM @output), ']');
END
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=89e597f01c8724fe4b80181f4aeb3c92)

PS. I use step-by-step transformations. This must allow you to understand how does this works. You may compact the code by combining a lot of statements into one where this is possible and by using parameters variables instead of intermediate user-defined ones.

Comment: Thank you for you reply I tried with below json.
'{"map":[{"hello":"a","text":"a","hello":"a"},{"text":"b","hello":"b"},{"text":"c","hello":"c"},{"text":"d","hello":"d"},{"text":"e","hello":"e"},{"text":"f","hello":"f"}]}'; Expected output: [a,b,c,d,e,f]

Comment: @biscuit765 Oops, I forget about a comma. Wait... done.

Comment: One more think I tried with sentence so it is return only first letter  '{"map":[{"text":"SQL databases tend to be rigid.","hello":'c'},{"text":"b"},{"text":"c"},{"text":"d"},{"text":"e"},{"text":"f"}]}' Expected output: ["SQL databases tend to be rigid.",b,c,d,e,f]

Comment: @biscuit765 If your values may contain spaces then remove space check from `@value` assigning but add TRIM().

Comment: I have one question suppose I have to remove one text from json so Can we implement on this